# pytest-qt to test menu functionality

Tags: python, testing, pyqt5, pytest, pytest-qt

I have a menu that I created

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
    ...
    create_menu_bar()
    ...

    def create_menu_bar(self):
        sheet_one = QtWidgets.QAction("sheet_one", self)
        sheet_one.triggered.connect(lambda: self.load_df(sheet_name="sheet one"))
        # more QActions createad

        menu = self.menuBar()
        menu.addAction(sheet_one)
        # drop down list
        sheet_five_menu = menu.addMenu("&sheet five")
        sheet_five_menu.addAction(sheet_five_one)
        sheet_five_menu.addAction(sheet_five_two)
        ...
```

I am trying to use pytest-qt to imitate a user clicking on one of the menu options, or clicking on one of the drop down menu options from `sheet_five_menu`

After reading the [documentation](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=mouse#tutorial) I have been able to understand how to open a window and view it. But I am having trouble understanding how to imitate user mouse clicks on my implementation of the menu. I read this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547862/simulating-mouse-click-in-menu-bar-and-toolbar-using-qtbot), implemented, but got this error.

E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'triggered'

test_app.py:11: AttributeError

what my test code currently looks like

```
def test_menu(qtbot):
    window = my_app.MainWindow()
    qtbot.add_widget(window)
    window.show()
    window.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'sheet_one').trigger()
```

**EDIT**

reading this [qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#actions) I understand that I should be able to trigger the QAction in this way but I am also getting error

revised code :

```
window.sheet_one.trigger()
```

but I am getting this error:

E       AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'sheet_one'

**I also tried** [example](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/195):

```
menu = window.create_menu_bar()
menu.actions()[0]
menu.trigger()
```

but am getting this error:

E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'trigger'

Comment: Your latest update is unclear: what does `create_menu_bar` return?

Comment: nothing, it is a call to the method to create the menu. I have a lot of different menu options and for my mental sake wanted to move all those creations into a method.

Comment: If it returns nothing, then `menu.actions()` should have raised the attribute error, which is not what you wrote. And if it returns a menu (as I suspect), then the third line should have been `menu.actions()[0].trigger()`, as the second line is completely useless.

Comment: got it thank you. I went with the findChild test instead of menu.actions()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findChild` uses the [`objectName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property to find any child QObject.

You are just setting the *text*, which is mainly a *visual* clue, but has absolutely no relation with the Qt object name, nor it should ever have any, since the text of an action could change during runtime, and updating the object name based on the text could become a serious problem.

By default QObjects have no object name set (an empty string), so `findChild()` will return `None` as there is no QAction that have `sheet_one` as its *objectName*.

You also used a space in the text, but you called `findChild()` using `sheet_one` with an underscore, so it wouldn't have worked anyway.

Note that if you intended to use that `sheet_one` as a reference to the variable assigned in `create_menu_bar` that would be completely pointless, since that is just a local reference and its name is irrelevant; even if you used an instance attribute it wouldn't have worked anyway, because Qt has absolutely **no** knowledge about python.

Just set the proper object name for the action:

```py
sheet_one.setObjectName('sheet_one')
```

Comment: I did this and got this error: E       TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

EDIT: forgot to update the testing code. works thank you kind person.

Comment: @Willy That is not caused by my answer. You probably tried to call `triggered()` (which is a signal, and, as such, not callable) instead of `trigger()`.

Comment: that is correct.